# WPF MVVM Caliburn Micro - Notify property on ViewModel from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have two views

- **Overview-View:** Contains of a datagrid which is binded to a IObservableCollection (the items get loaded from a repository (xml file) in the constructor)
- **Add-View:** Contains of some textboxes and a button which adds an item to the repository

  > What I want now is to notify the IObservableCollection of the Overview-View that an item was added to the xml file.

My first try was the following:

```
public IObservableCollection<Book> BookList
{
    get
    {
        this.LoadBookList();
        return this.bookList;
    }
    set
    {
        this.bookList = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.BookList);
    }
}
```

`this.LoadBookList()`initializes `this.bookList` from the repository.

This worked of course (the item is added in the xml file so the repository get it and sets the booklist), but there is the following problem:

I do also have a `Delete-Button` at each row of the datagrid which is binded to `DeleteItem(Book book)`

```
public void DeleteItem(Book book)
{
    var bookToRemove = this.BookList.Single(b => b.Equals(book));
    this.BookList.Remove(bookToRemove);
        
    this.BookRepository.WriteBookList(this.BookList);
}
```

But with the `this.LoadBookList();` call in the `BookList`-Property, the list gets filled with all items from the repository again when calling the `this.BookRepository.WriteBookList(this.BookList);`

One solution would be to use the backing property `this.bookList` in the `DeleteItem(...)`-Method... but is this the right approach?

Is there a better / more beautiful / cleaner approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the list only when `this.bookList` is null.
most probably, you will be filling bookList inside `LoadBookList()`.
So, modify the getter to:

```
if(this.bookList==null)
        this.LoadBookList();
 return this.bookList;
```

Note : initialise booklist inside LoadBookList().

Comment: yes the `this.bookList` is initialized inside `LoadBookList()`. It's a good point to only load the list when the backing property is null... but this still doesn't address the problem to reload the list when an item is added from the other ViewModel

Comment: So, you need to use eventAggregator , where the view model1 will subscribe & viewModel 2 will publish with newItemAdded -  http://putridparrot.com/blog/caliburn-micros-message-bus-event-aggregator/